# Run bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append without running script every time

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I have `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)` in my addon. I found that this function runs only if I clicked "Run Script"  `my_handler` is

```
def my_handler(scene):
    print('entered')
```

If I run my script then I change the frame the text `entered` is printed, but if I reopened my file without closing blender then change the frame it doesn't print unless I press on run script button in the text editor again, why this is happening? Does `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append` needs me to press the `Run Script` button every time I want it to be executed? The problem is that I installed my_Addon.py and when I close blender and open it my addon menu is there but when move frames the text `entered` is not printed.

Comment: Are you using the [`@persistent`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html#persistent-handler-example) decorator?

Comment: @batFINGER no, where I should use it?

Comment: Like the example in [link](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html#persistent-handler-example)